# Was Jonathan Harker using supernatural powers in the original Dracula novel?

Tags: dracula, powers

In the *Dracula*,  Stoker's original novel,  how was Jonathan Harker able to climb down the walls of Dracula's castle the same way Dracula did? Dracula was supernatural so he could do it supernaturally and glide like a lizard. But wasn't Jonathan Harker human?

Am I missing something?

Comment: I fixed your capitalization and grammar, but am unclear what you mean by 'glide like a lizard'.  I left it unchanged, but think it could be clarified.

Comment: ***Parkour*** .

Answer (score 15):

This is answered in the novel (emphasis mine):

> I have made the effort, and God helping me, have come safely back to this room. I must put down every detail in order. I went whilst my courage was fresh straight to the window on the south side, and at once got outside on this side. **The stones are big and roughly cut, and the mortar has by process of time been washed away between them.**
>
> <sup><sub>*Dracula*, Chapter 4</sub></sup>

So Harker is emphatically **not** using supernatural powers. The walls of medieval castle are not as smooth as modern brick walls, especially not when they're as old as Dracula's castle, and there was enough deterioration for Harker to keep a tenuous grip.

Comment: thank for letting me know. I was always wondering about that!

Comment: @darthfuture Happy to help. Don't forget to mark an answer as 'accepted' if you found it helpful (in this, and other questions)